# Filtering strings based on replicated numerical substrings at specific places in the string (in R)

Tags: r, string, filter

I have a list of file names/paths and I want to filter out the ones where the filename begins with the same six digits that are found after the first "/" in the path.  So for example, in the below list, numbers [1], [2], and [6] would be retained, whereas numbers [3], [4], and [5] would be removed from the new list.  I'm imagining it should be possible to split each string at the "/"s and compare the first six digits of the 2nd split with the last split, but I'm not sure how to implement this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
tail(processed_ARL_list)
[1] "220204/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30/ARL2200660.D/ARL2200660.pdf"                                                     
[2] "220204/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30/ARL2200661.D/ARL2200661.pdf"                                                     
[3] "220204/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30/REFTTO220204_.D/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30_REFTTO220204_.pdf"                    
[4] "220207/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02/REFTTO220207_.D/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02_REFTTO220207_.pdf"                    
[5] "220207/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02/SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.D/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02_SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.pdf"
[6] "220207/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02/SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.D/SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.pdf"
```

Comment: The logic does not make sense.  all your files have `220204` after the first `/`

Comment: This is just the last few of the list of files.  There are others with different dates.

Comment: But on this ones how do you want to separate 1,2,6 and 3,4,5?

Comment: I wanted to remove cases where the first 6 digits of the basename match the first six digits following the first '/'.  My solution below does the trick, if not in a very elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the result I was after using this looping method.  I feel like there might be a better way, but this will do for now.

```
    processed_results<-c()
    for (i in c(1:length(ARL_list))){
     filepath_split<-str_split(ARL_list[i],pattern="/")
     if(substr(unlist(filepath_split)[2],1,6)!=substr(unlist(filepath_split)[length(unlist(filepath_split))],1,6)){
       processed_results[i]<-TRUE
     }  else {
         processed_results[i]<-FALSE
     }
    }
    processed_ARL_list<-ARL_list[processed_results]
```

#### Output

```
tail(processed_ARL_list)
[1] "220128/220128 2022-01-28 07-53-13/ARL2200536.D/ARL2200536.pdf"                          
[2] "220128/220128 2022-01-28 07-53-13/ARL2200537.D/ARL2200537.pdf"                          
[3] "220128/220131 2022-01-31 16-10-36/REFTTO220131_.D/REFTTO220131_.pdf"                    
[4] "220204/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30/ARL2200660.D/ARL2200660.pdf"                          
[5] "220204/220204 2022-02-04 09-32-30/ARL2200661.D/ARL2200661.pdf"                          
[6] "220207/220204 2022-02-07 12-51-02/SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.D/SREF0186 METHYL EUGENOL.pdf"
```